# How to add malay language input type keyboard to android emulator?

Tags: android

I am developing a dictionary application, which supports three languages(English, chinese and malay). In my android emulator there is english and chinese language are available. Now I need to add malay language keyboard. How to add this..? Please Help me..! User will type in malay keyboard.. How to proceed...? Thanks in advance..!